# Workspaces bar as in ubuntu gnome flavour, please?

Tags: workspaces

Gnome has workspace bar that is like unity bar (launch bar) but on the right side and is big enough to see into, how do you install such on ubuntu?

https://afaikblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/workspaces.png

Comment: Press ctrl+super+s shortcut and you will see workspaces spread. While not a side bar, it gives you better understanding of how workspaces are organized. Plus , Unity workspaces extend horizontally, unlike gnome, so that wouldnt fit into a.bar anyway

Comment: Let me.know if you want this as full answer

Comment: I'd rather have a sidebar. It's easier to track what has what. ctrl+super+s didn't work, but I was playing with compiz recently.

Comment: sorry, it's super+s, ctrl key is not necessary there. Was typing the comment on phone yesterday. Well, as for the sidebar, there weren't any options that I know so far for that.  Viewing workspaces is typically internal to whatever desktop environment you use, thus unless compiz ( which is what Unity uses ) implements it or if there is a compiz plugin for that , then there's no way. Good question, but very low probability this exists